# Setting DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE in activate.bat not working WINDOWS

Tags: django, windows, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Pulling my hair out for this
I want to set my virtualenv with `virtualenvwrapper-win` on a windows 8 machine to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="[project-name].settings.testing"`

I edit the activate.bat of the testing env and add

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="<project-name>.settings.testing"
```

When I run `python manage.py runserver` under the virtualenv I get

```
Django version 1.8.5 using settings '<project-name>.settings.base'
```

and get the same things when I run the development virtual env.

The tutorial I am following indicates that I should set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODUlE` in a post activate file, and unset it on a predeactivatefile. Do these just not exist in the Windows version of virtuanenvwrapper??

Please let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally got it I am a newb

had to set it like this

```
"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<project-name>.settings.testing"
```

instead of

```
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="<project-name>.settings.testing"
```